# How can I fix a commercial door closer that jerks when opened, making loud noise?

Tags: doors, closer

[Take a look at this video](https://youtu.be/y0Y7CcJuENk) with sound on. This door closer, a [Dynasty 2000](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01HOXC5LM), works great and is quiet except in the instant that opening force is released and the door starts slowly closing.  It seems like the lack of tension allows the arm to jerk downward, making a loud noise.  Then the arm goes back up and the door closes properly.

Any idea how to make it stop slamming downward?  I tried adding a flat washer inside the bracket on the wall, as well as squeezing tighter with pliers the bracket closed in order to allow less play--however, I gather that there is supposed to be play in the arm, and my efforts made little difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't seem obvious from a visual inspection, but there is actually supposed to be a bolt and washer that holds the arm down onto to the main closer body pivot point.  I found each that fits and it fixed the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I run your video in slow motion (adjustable on youtube)

https://youtu.be/y0Y7CcJuENk

It shows that the wall part needs to be mounted about 1/4 inch higher.

It shows that the upper arm is tiled. Stop the door closing (half a way) and use leveler to level it out.

Comment: This may be somewhat correct, but I went with a more direct solution that was not obvious to me earlier.  Thanks.